# How to join a background colour to a background image using CSS?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, mousehover

I am having a problem with creating a hover effect with a PNG image and CSS. As the image below shows the image is a triangle notch. I am trying to make the background color extend left from the image and not overlap it as is happening in my example.

[Hover Background and Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMhX6.png)

```css
.parent-1:hover, .parent-2:hover, .parent-3:hover {
    background: #993408 url(/images/brown-notch.png) no-repeat right;
    background-size: contain;
    position: relative; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #fff !important;
    z-index: 1;   
}
```

Is there a way to make the background end where the image starts, so it becomes an arrow and be responsive?
I attempted this but it does not work responsively:

```css
.parent-1:hover::before, .parent-2:hover::before, .parent-3:hover::before {
    content: '';
    background-color: #993408;
    background-position: left;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    font-size: 1rem; 
    width: 96%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your image is 10px set the width on your :before elements to:

```
width: calc(100% - 10px);
```